# GitHub page can only be found on google when typing "username" AND "github"

Tags: github, github-pages, google-search

I have created a personal website using the Academic Theme for Hugo. I am hosting the page on GitHub.

The site works, but it is unfortunately very hard to find on google. Specifically, if I type my username followed by "github", it appears as the first result. However, it doesn't show at all if I type just my username into google. I went through until page 8 of the results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. May be useful to know that Google Console has not found an issue. Also, the page shows up as the first result on both Bing and DuckDuckGo when typing just my username.

This is the page: https://michagermann.github.io/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with Search Engine Optimisation (SEO).
Basically how search results work is that google has bots that go through the accessible page is on the internet and compile keywords for each page it hits, these are then linked to the search phrases people use. So username + github is an easy one as that is the majority of your url, however just your username will have many other results from others that have your username in their webpages, some of them multiple times, others once but have been around for a lot longer. There are a lot of variables to SEO but there are guides which can help with this.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=en
Googles Starter Guide for SEO

-- edit --

I would also hazard a guess and say that google is pulling back a lot of your publications which bing and duckduckgo aren't, and as these will likely have been accessed more will I expect be higher in the search algorithm.

--- edit 2 ---

**Link Building**
This is very important for SEO, this is where external sites link to your sites. The easiest way to achieve this is through your personal profiles on Twitter, LinkedIn, Github ect.
Writing Blogs can also have other people link to your profile and thus increase your link building.

DO NOT PAY FOR LINK BUILDING
Link building for Google is based off of high quality sites - every site has a ranking, a low quality site will have a much lower affect on your SEO score, and thus not result in any noticeable movement. Paid link building usually involves low quality sites

**Site Maps**
If you have a multi-page site (Yours isn't) then site maps help search bots navigate the important pages easier, and can help increase rankings.

**Meta Tags**
These are extremely important, although some tags are more important than others, title(included with the  element), author and description are some of the more important meta tags.

I'm not an SE optimizer and haven't done much SEO for a few years so this is from old experience and I don't guarantee it is all correct as of writing, however I expect it hasn't changed that often. SEO is a complex area and search engines have different preferences. But hopefully this helps. A lot of SEO comes through time rather than right away through link building so that is also something to keep in mind

Comment: Do you have any more concrete advice re SEO? The thing is that Hugo's academic theme template is used by many other academics out there, and they do not appear to have this problem (that is, their page does show).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a few additional bits, but i'm not really tuned into modern SEO practices. The biggest thing however is still link building, add your link to all of your public searchable profiles that have a relevancy and that will help

Comment: It turns out the issue was that I used the same "About me" text on both my personal and my institutional (uni) website. This led to google categorizing my website as a duplicate and omitting it from the results. Changing the about me text on one of the pages resolved the issue. For more details, see here: https://cognitiveseo.com/blog/17778/google-omitted-results/

Answer (score 0):

First of all know about how the google search works....and if you simply type your name it won't show your website as such because there may be multiple highly prioritized websites are there with this name in the first place......

And if type yourname.github its nothing but the direct address of your page so that's why it is shown in the first place